# Python TypeError with tuples and integers

Tags: python, python-2.7

This code is showing me the following error, no idea why:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testSolver.py", line 24, in 
    S[j: j+NFM[i], :] = S[i] / 2.0 
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple

```
import numpy as np
mu = np.array([ -0.8611363115, -0.3399810435, 0.3399810435, 0.8611363115 ])
wt = np.array([ 0.3478548451, 0.6521451549, 0.6521451549, 0.3478548451 ])  
NCM = [0.0,1.0,2.0,3.0]
NFM = [3,4,5]
mt = [0,1,2]
S = [1,1,1]
totNFM = np.sum(NFM)
Q = S
psi = np.zeros((totNFM + 1 , 4))
phi = np.zeros(totNFM)
FMMID = np.zeros((totNFM, 1))
delta = np.zeros((totNFM, 1))
j = 0
#Compute Discretization##
for i in range(0, len(NFM)):
    delta[j: j+NFM[i]] = (NCM[i+1] - NCM[i])/NFM[i]
    S[j: j+NFM[i], :] = S[i] / 2.0 
    FMMID[j: j+NFM[i]] = RegMat[i]
    j = np.sum[NFM[0:i]]
```

Comment: What is your intention with ` S[j: j+NFM[i], :]` ? The comma shouldnt be there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct sintax when working with slices is `[start:stop:step]`

So  `S[j: j+NFM[i], :]` is incorrect. It should be  `S[j: j+NFM[i] :]` without the comma.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the comma:

```
  S[j: j+NFM[i], :] = S[i] / 2.0
```

It should be :

```
  S[j:j+NFM[i]:] = S[i] / 2.0
```

And since your aren't using step you can use :

```
  S[j:j+NFM[i]] = S[i] / 2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think the syntax is correct. `S[j: j+NFM[i], :] = S[i] / 2.0` This is actually creating a row. The problem was with an arbitrary source declaration, `S = [1,1,1]` which was really a typo (TypeError). I changed it to `S = np.zeros((totNFM,4))` and the error vanished.

Comment: No, the sintax was __incorrect__. You cannot separate by commas nor pass tuples as 'arguments' when slicing.

Comment: I am sorry for not being clear. S = np.zeros((totNFM, 4)) with totNFM = 12 is creating a 12 x 4 matrix of zeros. With j = 0, S[j: j+NFM[i], :] is giving you NFM(i) number of rows of that matrix. Like if NFM(i) = 4, S =array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
 Thus, you are right in your logic.